# R Matrix Sum Floating Point Sum Margin Error

Tags: r, anova

I have this data:

```
   SEX LS  GPA
1    M DO 2.56
2    M DO 2.70
3    M DO 3.04
4    M DO 1.42
5    M FS 3.02
6    M FS 2.67
7    M FS 2.35
8    M FS 1.80
9    M CO 3.41
10   M CO 2.97
11   M CO 2.23
12   M CO 2.31
13   M AP 2.28
14   M AP 3.73
15   M AP 2.05
16   M AP 2.61
17   M HO 2.57
18   M HO 2.81
19   M HO 3.01
20   M HO 3.40
21   F DO 3.33
22   F DO 1.80
23   F DO 2.50
24   F DO 3.04
25   F FS 3.87
26   F FS 3.00
27   F FS 3.25
28   F FS 2.76
29   F CO 3.14
30   F CO 4.00
31   F CO 2.66
32   F CO 2.91
33   F AP 3.69
34   F AP 2.55
35   F AP 3.21
36   F AP 2.86
37   F HO 3.09
38   F HO 1.99
39   F HO 3.46
40   F HO 3.61
```

I am running an ANOVA on the data, and to find the parameters I'm doing the following:

calculate the means:

```
mu_grand <- mean(data$GPA)
mu_alpha <- aggregate(data$GPA,list(data$SEX),mean)$x
mu_beta <- aggregate(data$GPA,list(data$LS),mean)$x
mu_alpha_beta <- matrix(aggregate(data$GPA,list(data$SEX,data$LS),mean)$x,nrow=2)
```

calculate the additive effects

```
alpha <- mu_alpha - mu_grand
beta <- mu_beta - mu_grand
```

calculate the interactive effects

```
a1 <- rep(alpha[1],length(beta))
a2 <- rep(alpha[2],length(beta))

ab1 <- a1 + beta
ab2 <- a2 + beta

ab <- rbind(ab1,ab2)

alpha_beta <- mu_alpha_beta - (mu_grand + ab)
```

Here is alpha_beta:

```
ab1  0.0105  0.02925 -0.07575  0.1855 -0.1495
ab2 -0.0105 -0.02925  0.07575 -0.1855  0.1495
```

If I want to find the sum of alpha_beta I get

```
sum(alpha_beta)
[1] -4.440892e-16
```

While this is definitely within floating point accuracy, I'm wondering why there is any error at all when if you just add up all the numbers manually you get 0?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at that number it is extremely small. `R` only calculates to around 15 digits so this is just rounding error. Using the package `gmp` we can see the laws of physics aren't broken.

**Load required package**

```
require("gmp") #Required package
```

**Read in data**

```
data<- read.table(text="SEX LS  GPA
1    M DO 2.56
                  2    M DO 2.70
                  3    M DO 3.04
                  4    M DO 1.42
                  5    M FS 3.02
                  6    M FS 2.67
                  7    M FS 2.35
                  8    M FS 1.80
                  9    M CO 3.41
                  10   M CO 2.97
                  11   M CO 2.23
                  12   M CO 2.31
                  13   M AP 2.28
                  14   M AP 3.73
                  15   M AP 2.05
                  16   M AP 2.61
                  17   M HO 2.57
                  18   M HO 2.81
                  19   M HO 3.01
                  20   M HO 3.40
                  21   F DO 3.33
                  22   F DO 1.80
                  23   F DO 2.50
                  24   F DO 3.04
                  25   F FS 3.87
                  26   F FS 3.00
                  27   F FS 3.25
                  28   F FS 2.76
                  29   F CO 3.14
                  30   F CO 4.00
                  31   F CO 2.66
                  32   F CO 2.91
                  33   F AP 3.69
                  34   F AP 2.55
                  35   F AP 3.21
                  36   F AP 2.86
                  37   F HO 3.09
                  38   F HO 1.99
                  39   F HO 3.46
                  40   F HO 3.61", header=T,row.names=1)
```

**Code**

```
data$GPA<-as.bigq(data$GPA) #Converts to class `bigq`

#Special function because sapply was converting data to raw format
meanL<-function(L){ 
  x<-rep(0,length(L))
  x<-as.bigq(x)

  for(i in 1:length(L)){
    x[i]<-mean(L[[i]])
  }
  return(x)
}

#This section is changed to handle the new class `bigq`
mu_grand <- mean(data$GPA)
mu_alpha <- meanL(split(data$GPA,data$SEX))
mu_beta <- meanL(split(data$GPA,data$LS))
mu_alpha_beta <- matrix(meanL(split(data$GPA,as.factor(paste(data$SEX,data$LS,sep="-")))),nrow=2)



alpha <- mu_alpha - mu_grand
beta <- mu_beta - mu_grand

a1 <- rep(alpha[1],length(beta))
a2 <- rep(alpha[2],length(beta))

ab1 <- a1 + beta
ab2 <- a2 + beta

ab<-matrix(c(ab1,ab2),ncol=5,byrow=T) #The same as rbind but needed to work with objects of class 'bigq'.
alpha_beta <- mu_alpha_beta - (mu_grand + ab)
sum(alpha_beta)

Big Rational ('bigq') :
[1] 0
```

This is a nice thought experiment but its a pain in the **s to work this `gmp` because as you can see functions like `aggregate` and `sapply` don't play well with it. Moral of the story when you see incredibly small number i.e. `1e-16` and you are expecting 0 you can just assume they are 0.